# Providing fusing for motors if system is protected by a fused disconnect?

Tags: power

So I was told that at the site of install the customer is providing us with a 30A fused disconnect so we can run 3 motors for our machine (2× 5hp ones (non simultaneous), and 1x 3hp one which can run when one of the 5hp ones runs)

Here is my question

If the circuit is fused up stream via the 30A disconnect would you still need to fuse all the 3 motors with their required fuse sizes at 480V? So in this case the 3hp would get a 6A fuse slow blow , and the 2x  5 hp ones would get 10A fuses.??

Comment: Each motor branch circuit must have appropriate disconnecting means, short circuit and ground fault protection, motor control device and motor overload protection. There is more than one way to meet the requirements. Everything must conform to the applicable electrical codes. The details should be reviewed by a qualified electrician who is familiar with the applicable codes, not by volunteers given a brief description on the internet. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: You've already received an answer for this in your previous question, haven't you?